A gap in Stein & Shakarchi's Theorem 4.8?
Theorem 4.8 of Chapter 2 reads:

Theorem 4.8 Suppose $f$ is a holomorphic function in a region $\Omega$ that vanishes on a sequence of distinct points with a limit point in $\Omega$. Then $f$ is identically $0$.

The proof is broken into two pieces. First, it is shown that if $z_0\in\Omega$ is a limit point of the zeroes $w_k$'s, then $f$ vanishes throughout an open ball around $z_0$. I have no trouble understanding this part. The remaining proof employs connectivity of $\Omega$ to show that $f$ vanishes throughout $\Omega$. For this, they let $U$ be the interior of the zeroes of $f$ and argue that this is closed (that it's nonempty is due to the first part; that it's open is by definition):

The set $U$ is also closed since if $z_n\in U$ and $z_n\to z$, then $f(z) = 0$ by continuity, and $f$ vanishes in a neighborhood of $z$ by the argument above. Hence $z\in U$.

How is the bolded claim justified? The "above argument" depended on $z_0$ being inside $\Omega$. Thus, we'd be done if we could show $z\in \Omega$. However, I don't see how. Can someone explain?

The domain of $f$ is $\Omega$ and $U\subset\Omega$, no?

@TedShifrin Sure, one can assume that $\Omega$ is the whole domain of $f$ (rather than just a subset of it). Let's assume this for argument's sake. But still, I don't see how the limit of a sequence zeroes in $U$ (which, as you point out, is a subset of $\Omega$) will lie inside $\Omega$.

The question boils down to this: If $f$ vanishes throughout some ball around each of the $z_n$'s, can we conclude $\lim_n z_n\in \Omega$?

If you're agreeing that we should assume $\Omega$ is the full domain of $f$, I don't see what the issue is.

I suppose they want to prove that $U$ is closed in induced topology in $\Omega$, therefore they need to show that if $z \in \Omega$ and sequence $z_n \to z, z_n \in U$, then $z \in U$.

Ah, sì! That makes sense, @AndreyZherdev! Finally, I can rest for the day.
